# If all characters in the name is uppercase, put a comma in front of it

Tags: c#, string

The names I use in the program are as follows: `Jenny BLACK`, `Helen BROWN EYE`, `Henna Tamara GREEN`. If the person has more than one first name or more than one surname, I want to put a comma just before the surname. How can I do that? We can distinguish that a string is a surname by the fact that all letters are capitalized.

With a method like this, maybe I can get what I want a very long way, but it doesn't sound professional at all.

```
string author_final = "";
var aut_examp = new List<string>{"Jenny BLACK", "Helen BROWN EYE", "Henna Tamara GREEN"};
if (aut_examp.Count > 1)
{
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var aut in aut_examp)
    {
        var and = i < aut_examp.Count ? "&" : "";

        var explodes = aut.Split(new[] { $" " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var ex in explodes)
        {
            if (ex.All(char.IsUpper) // ...
            // With a method like this, maybe I can get what I want a very long way, but it doesn't sound professional at all.
        }
        author_final += aut + and;
        i++;
    }
}
else
{
    author_final = aut_examp[0];
}
```

Comment: You've actually selected an answer that has a wrong solution as it always inserts a comma. However, the biggest hint it to split the problem into pieces. First get the names out, then count the first and family names, and if there are multiple of any, then put the name together again using a comma.

Comment: Note that if you've got a working solution, there's also [codereview.se] where your entire source code gets dissected :)

Comment: You could make this question clearer by showing the expect output (quite a few answers produce `Jenny, BLACK`, but you say you don't want the comma for names with a single forename and single surname).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split names with `space` as a delimiter and then add comma for first upper case word.

Here are my 2 cents,

```
public static string GetProcessedName(string name)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Flag to keep track of comma addition to output string.
    var commaAdded = false;
    foreach(var word in name.Split())
    {
        if(word == word.ToUpper() && !commaAdded)
        {
            sb.Append($", {word}");
            commaAdded = true;
        }
        else
           sb.Append(" "+word);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now call this method to the actual method,

```
var aut_examp = new List<string>{"Jenny BLACK", "Helen BROWN EYE", "Henna Tamara GREEN"};
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var aut in examp)
   sb.AppendLine(GetProcessedName(aut));

string author_final = sb.ToString();
```

---

[Try online : .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o2pu9M)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *regular expressions* for the problem:

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = "Torin OAKENSHIELD";

 result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<!,)\s+[\p{Lu}]+[\s\p{Lu}]*", ",$&");
```

Here we use *pattern* `(?<!,)\s+[\p{Lu}]+[\s\p{Lu}]*` to match and then replace:

```
(?<!,)      - negative look - NOT started with comma
\s+         - followed by at least one (one or more) whitespace
[\p{Lu}]+   - followed by at least one capital letter
[\s\p{Lu}]* - followed by any number (zero or more) white spaces or 
              capital letters.
```

In your case, you can try *Linq* and *Regular expressions* combination:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  var aut_examp = new List<string> {
    "Jenny BLACK", "Helen BROWN EYE", "Henna Tamara GREEN" };

  var demo = aut_examp
    .Select(name => Regex.Replace(name, @"(?<!,)\s+[\p{Lu}]+[\s\p{Lu}]+", ",$&"))
    .ToList();

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, demo));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Jenny, BLACK
Helen, BROWN EYE
Henna Tamara, GREEN
```

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ you could break your names into words, then recombine them with "take while name contains lower case chars", a comma, "skip while name contains lower chars"

```
new [] {"Jenny BLACK", "Helen BROWN EYE", "Henna Tamara GREEN"}
.Select(n => 
  string.Join(" ", n.Split().TakeWhile(o => o.Any(Char.IsLower))) + 
  ", " + 
  string.Join(" ", n.Split().SkipWhile(o => o.Any(Char.IsLower)))
);
```

I think I'd rather just ask regex to find me the index of the first all uppercase word and insert a comma..

```
new [] {"Jenny BLACK", "Helen BROWN EYE", "Henna Tamara GREEN"}
.Select(n => n.Insert(Regex.Match(n, " [A-Z]+\\b").Index, ","))
```